# How can I check to see if a component exists in Mura CMS?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I need to be able to look for a component, by name, inside of a site, but I've not been able to find documentation that shows me how to do that. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You might try the MuraCMS Community Support resources. https://docs.murasoftware.com/v7-1/content-managers/getting-support/ This question isn't related to a programming issue, so it will probably get closed.

Comment: I found this code example from Steve that should get you headed in the right direction. https://gist.github.com/stevewithington/9009257